# Getting minimum value by output block

Tags: list, terraform, numbers, min

I need to get minimum value in output block using variable type number with list

**Terraform:**

```
variable "ports" {
   type = list(number)
   default = [12,16,23]
}

output "ports_count" {
  value = length(var.ports)
}

output "ports_min" {
  value = min(var.ports)
}
```

**Output**

```
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 11, in output "ports_min":
│   11:   value = min(var.ports)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.ports is a list of number, known only after apply
│ 
│ Invalid value for "numbers" parameter: number required.
```

Comment: Try `min([12,16,23]...)`.

Comment: I need use variable to get value :( it's exercise

Comment: Then try setting it as a local variable.

Comment: can you provide example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since output will require the value to be known, I suggest using local variables:

```
locals {
  ports = [12,16,23]
}
```

Then in the outputs, you would do the following:

```
output "ports_min" {
  value = min(local.ports...)
}
```

This will output `12`. The `...` is function expansion operator [1].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments

Comment: Good luck with your exercise. :)